# What is the purpose of $.cache in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, memory-leaks

I see that the event handlers registered through `.on()` are held in `$.cache`.
I also see that the event handlers are also held in `$(elem).data()`.

The objects held in `$.cache` refer to the DOM nodes on which the events are registered. This leads to memory leak when the DOM nodes are detached, and this makes `.off()` calls mandatory.

I have a situation where I don't know when the DOM node (to which I attached the event handler) is being detached. While I can hold the reference to that DOM node in my code and call `.off()` to clean up, it doesn't seem nice, because it is not straightforward to know when the DOM node is being removed.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *"What is the best way to do this?"*

If you're going to use jQuery, you *must* use its API for removing elements, and you must use the proper methods, otherwise, as you stated, you'll have memory leaks.

If you don't know when the DOM node is being removed, and if it is causing a leak, I'd assume this means that you are using another library alongside jQuery. That's just not a good idea for this very reason.

You need to ensure that any elements affected by jQuery are removed by jQuery. There's also some data stored in `$.cache` that you didn't explicitly set. This means that *all* elements should be removed with jQuery, instead of just those that you *think* may have data.

---

> *"What is the purpose of `$.cache` in jQuery?"*

To associate handlers and other data with elements. The link between the data and the elements is basically a serial number stored on an expando property on the element.

If you remove the element without jQuery, the associated data in `$.cache` is orphaned.

The purpose of this approach was to prevent potential leaks. Unfortunately it potentially creates more severe leaks.

Comment: 1. If the relation between element and the handlers is maintained through a serial number (and if the handler is not referring to the element), I don't see a reason why .cache entries should lead to memory leak. For some reason, I don't know how justifiable it is, the cache entry is referring to the element.

I am curious to know why the reference to element is required.

2. I am not aware of the cases in which expando of an element cannot hold references to objects (handlers) directly. If expando can hold references, I don't see a need for parallel structure like .cache to hold references.

Comment: @user968903: 1. They only lead to leaks if you don't use jQuery's methods that remove the related `$.cache` entry when removing the element. The serial number is the only connection between the two, so if element with serial `123` is removed, but jQuery doesn't remove entry `123` in `$.cache`, then that entry is now referring to data that no longer has a corresponding element, and will never be cleaned up. The justification was potential memory leaks that exist primarily in IE6 and perhaps IE7. Now that those browsers are nearly gone, I don't know if this approach is good.

Comment: @user968903: 2. I think that modern browsers generally clean up elements when removed, so it probably isn't so much of an issue anymore. I believe it was primarily IE6/7 that had issues. I think there may still be potential memory leaks with respect to closures, where an element has a handler that has in its variable scope a circular reference to itself, but I'm not sure if that's an issue today or not. I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 6):

I ran in to a similar situation where Knockout is used to add and remove dom trees from the document. However, jquery is used to attach event listeners to these dom trees. When knockout removes dom elements from the document the listeners are not unbound so the dom tree is never eligible for garbage collection. We have added a clean up function that trawls through the jquery $.cache everytime the hash changes and finds even handlers that are bound to dom trees that are not in the document. It then unbinds the listeners thus making the dom tree eligible for garbage collection and fixing most of the leaks that we are seeing i.e. round trip round the app used to leak 13MB now it leaks just 3MB with these changes in place.

```
for (var i in $.cache) {
            if ($.cache.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

                if ($.cache[i].handle && $.cache[i].handle.elem && document !== $.cache[i].handle.elem && !jQuery.contains(document, $.cache[i].handle.elem)) {
                    //we have an event handler pointing to a detached dom element!
                    //this is a memory leak as this detached dom element cannot be garbage collected until
                    //all references to it are removed. So lets delete the event handler to get memory back!
                    var orphan = $($.cache[i].handle.elem);
                    $('body').append(orphan);
                    orphan.off();
                    orphan.remove();
                    orphan = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like this is a result of a bug in knockout 3.0.0, When I upgraded to 3.1.0 the memory leak went away without the need for the above code!