# angular.element.cache, what's this thing?

Tags: angularjs

recently, I'm struggling with a bug, that's angular doesn't work in the page. 
I checked this out and found that somehow, all the properties are removed from angular.element.cache
Can someone explain what is this thing and for what reason to clear it ?

Comment: Do you mind showing what you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

`angular.element.cache` is AngularJS exposing the jQuery or jQlite cache, i.e. the data structure used to associate data with DOM nodes.

Comment: $.cache === angular.element.cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304768/what-is-the-purpose-of-cache-in-jquery

Comment: @ArielM. not necessarily, depending on whether you use jQlite or jQuery. I think that'll also change in AngularJS 2.0.